# how to compare two objects in class using __cmp__ method in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
class Box(object):
def __init__(self, ival):
    self.value = ival
def __cmp__(self,other):
    if self.value < other:
        return 
    elif self.value > other:
        return 1
    else:return 0
```

But when I wanna test the program with :

```
Box(2) < Box(2)
Box(2) <= Box(2)
Box(1) >= Box(2)
Box(3) > Box(2)
Box(0) == Box(1)
Box(0) != Box(0)
```

Part of the code below:

```
Box(1) >= Box(2)
Box(3) > Box(2)
Box(0) == Box(1)
```

has shown

> TypeError: an integer is required

Anyone knows why?

EDITED :I added the -1 before but somehow I deleted it -.-
sorry for asking such careless question!

Comment: `if self.value < other:
        return ` you forgot -1.

Comment: Also, FWIW, you're probably better off defining `__eq__` and `__lt__` and then using something like `functools.total_ordering` to fill in the other rich comparison method.

Comment: is `__cmp__` still available in python 3? I read that it has been removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compare `self.value` to `other.value`:

```
def __cmp__(self,other):
    if self.value < other.value:
        return -1
    elif self.value > other.value:
        return 1
    else:return 0
```

otherwise you're comparing an integer to an object

Answer (score 3):

Python's __cmp__ magic method returns an integer > 0 if greater, 0 if equal, and < 0 if less. You can see that in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__).

Your __cmp__ function returns None for the 'less than' comparison.

```
class Box(object):
    def __init__(self, ival):
        self.value = ival
    def __cmp__(self,other):
        if self.value < other:
            return   # return None   <--------- bad
        elif self.value > other:
            return 1
        else:return 0
```

It should be:

```
class Box(object):
    def __init__(self, ival):
        self.value = ival
    def __cmp__(self,other):
        if self.value < other:
            return -1  # <--------- yay!
        elif self.value > other:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

As others pointed out, if you are seeking to compare a Box to another Box, you should modify your __cmp__ method to compare `other.value`, not just `other`.

```
class Box(object):
    def __init__(self, ival):
        self.value = ival
    def __cmp__(self,other):
        if self.value < other.value:
            return -1
        elif self.value > other.value:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `__cmp__` method id deprecated now - you should really use the so-called "rich comparison" methods - `__eq__` and friends.

The error is being caused because you are attempting to compare an integer with a `Box` object, and no such comparison is defined. Perhaps what you need is more like

```
        if self.value < other.value:
            return -1
        elif self.value > other.value:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

but then you might need to take into account whether `other` is a `Box` or not. If it's not, what does the comparison mean?

Answer (score 0):

[Doc reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp) on `__cmp__`:

> Should *return* a **negative integer** if `self < other`, **zero** if `self == other`, a **positive integer** if `self > other`

So all your branches should return an integer but the `if` branch is returning `None`.